# Implement search for JPA and Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to implement properly search functionality for database table. I tried this approach:

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping
    public Page<TransactionDTO> find(TransactionFilterDTO filter, Pageable page) {
        return searchRepository
                .findTransactionsByFilter(mapper.toFilter(filter), page)
                .map(mapper::toDTO);
    }
```

Filer DTO:

```
public class TransactionFilterDTO {

    private String name;

    private Integer id;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime from;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime to;
    ... // getters and setter
}
```

Search implementation:

```
@Repository
public class TransactionSearchRepositoryImpl implements TransactionSearchRepository {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TransactionSpecification specification;

    @Override
    public Page<Transaction> findTransactionsByFilter(TransactionFilter filter, @Nullable Pageable page) {


        List<Transaction> transactions = transactionRepository
                .findAll(specification.getFilter(filter));

        int totalCount = transactions.size();

        if(page != null) {
           transactions = transactions
                   .stream()
                   .skip(page.getOffset())
                   .limit(page.getPageSize())
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }

        return new PageImpl<>(transactions, page, totalCount);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface TransactionSearchRepository {

    Page<Transaction> findTransactionsByFilter(TransactionFilter filter, Pageable page);
}
```

Is there some better way to implement a search functionality? This solution is very ugly in my view.

Answer (score 2):

In JPA you could use [`JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) in repository, with that you could utilize it's method.

#### TransactionRepository

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long>,
                                                JpaSpecificationExecutor<Transaction> {


}
```

If you look at the source of `JpaSpecificationExecutor` it has,

> ```
> Page< T > findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
> ```

With that you just pass the specification and Pageable to return what you expected.

#### Specification

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class TransactionSpecification implements Specification<Transaction> {

       private TransactionFilter transactionFilter;

       @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DataImport> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
            // You could add multiple Predicates based on the transactionFilter
            return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("table_name"), "value");
        }
}
```

#### Controller

```
    @Autowired
    private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public Page<TransactionDTO> find(TransactionFilterDTO filter, Pageable page) {
        TransactionFilter transactionFilter = mapper.toFilter(filter);
        return transactionRepository.findAll(new TransactionSpecification(transactionFilter), page);
    }
```

I am pretty late answering but you could give it a try